# Solving the stationary points of this system

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative

[image]

I couldn't get very far with this at all, I was only able to find the trivial solutions.

$$
a=1/2 \mathbf{v^T}(A-\alpha)\mathbf{v}
$$
if we differentiate this and by knowing that $a^T=a$ we get:
$$
\frac{\partial a}{\partial v_i}=\begin{bmatrix}
           \delta_{1i} \\
           \delta_{2i} \\
           \vdots \\
           \delta_{ni}
         \end{bmatrix} (A-\alpha)\mathbf{v}=\sum^n_k(A_{ik}-\alpha)v_k
$$

However apart from the trivial solutions:  $A=I\alpha$ and $\mathbf{v=0}$ I can't seem to solve it.

I'm quite sure I differentiated it correctly.  Any help would be grateful.  Thank you

Comment: You write $A-\alpha$, but one is a matrix and the other is a scalar, no?

Comment: Yes, how would you want me to differentiate between them

Comment: It's not that, it is just that I'm not sure you can "factor out" like that, as the operation inside the parenthesis is not defined.

Comment: I suppose that by $A-\alpha$ you mean $A-\alpha I$?

Answer (score 0):

You’re close. Convert the system of equations ${\partial a\over\partial v_i}=0$ that you derived into matrix form: $$(\mathbf A-\alpha\mathbf I)\mathbf v=0.$$ It should now be obvious that this is satisfied by any $\mathbf v\in\ker(\mathbf A-\alpha\mathbf I)$. This kernel is nontrivial when $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $\mathbf A$.

This might’ve been easier to spot had you computed the differential of $a$ directly: $$a=\frac12(\mathbf v^T\mathbf A\mathbf v+\alpha|\mathbf v|^2)=\frac12(\mathbf v^T\mathbf A\mathbf v+\alpha\mathbf v^T\mathbf v)=\frac12\mathbf v^T(\mathbf A-\alpha\mathbf I)\mathbf v$$ so $$\operatorname{d}a=\mathbf v^T(\mathbf A-\alpha\mathbf I).$$ $\mathbf A-\alpha\mathbf I$ is symmetric, so the condition $\operatorname{d}a=0$ is equivalent to $(\mathbf A-\alpha\mathbf I)\mathbf v=0$.